# Search over Item IDs in Amazon SDB

Tags: nosql, amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

Is it possible to search through Item IDs in Amazon SDB, something like:

```
SELECT * FROM myDomain WHERE ItemName like '1234%'
```

I'm new to nosql, making first app with Amazon SimpleDB, figuring out best schema for my data.

Was thinking of making ItemName a concatenation of userId, topicId and, say, a timestamp - for a forum, for instance. So that getting all posts of a single user would be by searching through ItemNames, which are, I suppose, indexed - perhaps, a faster search.

Or should I just assign unique IDs to my items and never bother with their sorting, naming convention etc. - doing search only through Attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.. you search through Item IDs in Amazon SimpleDB and you can even sort your data using item IDs too. Here are some examples of query -

```
select * from domain where itemName() like '1234%'
select * from domain limit N
select * from domain where itemName() like '1234%' order by itemName() limit 2500.
```

For more details you refer following documentation -

http://www.sdbexplorer.com/documentation/simpledb--how-to-run-select-query.html
http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1232
http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1231

Disclosure: I'm a developer of [SDB Explorer](http://www.sdbexplorer.com/).

Comment: Thank you so much! For the answer and for the excellent tool too!
Read tons of docs and missed the `itemName()` syntax.